# Derivative of a matrix with a vector

Tags: calculus, tensors

Let there be three matrix F ,A (size (t+1) * t) and B (size t * t) and B is a function of x and x (size n) be a vector.

$ F=AB(x) $

Find the derivative of F w.r.t x.

When I tried to find the derivative of the vector the matrices sizes become incompatible and the composition of matrix A with the derivative of matrix B fails.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of matrix derivative  $\frac{dC(x)}{dx'}$ is the jacobian and $\frac{dC(x)'}{dx}=\left(\frac{dC(x)}{dx'}\right)'$. So in your case $\frac{dC(x)}{dx}=\left(\frac{dC'(x)}{dx'}\right)'$